# Does memcpy preserve a trivial object's validity?

Tags: c++, c++20

If one has a valid object of a trivial type (in this context, a trivial type satisfies the trivially move/copy constructible concepts), and one `memcpy`s it to a region of uninitialised memory, is the copied region of memory a valid object?

Assumption from what I've read: An object is only valid if it's constructor has been called.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'd be too embarassed to beg for karma simply by copy/pasting [cppreference.com's writeup on the subject](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/) as the authoritative answer: "Underlying bytes can be copied by std::memcpy...". The End.

Comment: Inheritance could also be involved here.  A trivial type can derive from another trivial type.  You would need to be sure that whatever you are `memcpy`-ing is truly the most derived type of the object in both source and destination or you would end up with slicing

Comment: A [_trivial type_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TrivialType) is not the same as a type with a trivial copy or move constructor. The difference is important here. What exactly are the conditions you want to know about?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - I think your link is broken

Comment: [This was the link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable) I wanted to originally reference.

Comment: Yes, but so does assignment, which you should always use instead, as it also works for non-trivial objects, if they have been declared and defined correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copying an object of a trivial type with `std::memcpy` into properly sized and aligned storage will implicitly begin the lifetime of a new object at that location.

There is a category of types called [implicit-lifetime type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Implicit-lifetime_types)  whose requirements are :

> - a scalar type, or
> - an array type, or
> - an aggregate class type, or
> - **a class type that has**
>
>   - **at least one trivial eligible constructor, and**
>   - **a trivial, non-deleted destructor,**
> - or a cv-qualified version of one of above types.

[Trivial class types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TrivialType)  meet these requiements.

Objects of implicit-lifetime type have the property that [their lifetime can be started implicitly](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Object_creation) be several functions or operations :

> - operations that begin lifetime of an array of type `char`, `unsigned char`, or `std::byte`, (since C++17) in which case such objects are created in the array,
> - call to following allocating functions, in which case such objects are
>
>   - created in the allocated storage:
>   - operator new
>   - operator new[]
>   - std::malloc
>   - std::calloc
>   - std::realloc
>   - std::aligned_alloc (since C++17)
> - call to following object representation copying functions, in which case such objects are created in the destination region of storage or the result:
>
>   - **std::memcpy**
>   - std::memmove
>   - std::bit_cast (since C++20)